# Cannot find 'Stereo Mix' on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dell-latitude, stereo

I have a DELL Latitude E6400 model laptop, on which installs a Windows 7 system. But I cannot find 'Stereo Mix' in 'Sound' -> 'Recording Devices', even if I try to 'Show Disabled/Disconnected Devices'. Hence I guess it's a driver problem.

My current driver is from DELL official website - R239286( IDT92HDxxxAudio ).
Any ideas on how I can proceed with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the reason behind "Stereo Mix" becoming a missing option?](http://superuser.com/questions/299082/whats-the-reason-behind-stereo-mix-becoming-a-missing-option)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think Windows 7 hasn't got a 'Stereo mix' anymore. At least, it doesn't show in my Windows either (Realtek onboard soundcard).

Comment: I find this post from microsoft website: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7music/thread/9bf67267-329a-45f5-a6ce-902c6fa6b4bc

Quotations:
"The problem lies in the drivers. The drivers supplied by microsoft for the Realtek devices as well as the newer drivers supplied
by Realtek are not good drivers, they do not have the feature."

"The solution, as I had to find for myself, is to simply uninstall the newer drivers and disable the automatic driver installation
policy, then install the older Vista_Win7_R237 drivers."

Comment: It seems that 'Stereo Mix' is on the way out, and WASAPI comes to the rescue.

Comment: This answer is just plain not correct. Stereo mix can appear in windows 7, many people have reported it.